# How does Sonata Admin 2.3 load assets?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

In the new standard_layout template, javascripts are loaded like this:

```
{% for javascript in admin_pool.getOption('javascripts', []) %}
```

It seems `admin_pool` is a service in the DI container and is defined in this file : `Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Pool.php`.

What responsibilities does the `admin_pool` service have and how does it load assets? I'm looking for a detailed explanation of the execution flow from the above twig statement to the loading of the actual (e.g. javascript) assets from disk.

Comment: It simply returns an array of JS file names and puts those in a script tag...

Comment: What do you need the info for? Do you want to add or override assets? The full assets can be found here: http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

The javascripts and stylesheets (assets) are managed by the admin pool.

You can add the assets to your `app/config/config.yml` if you want to modify your assets dynamically or you need more advanced configuration you should look to `sonata.admin.pool` service which is implemented by `vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Admin/Pool.php`

**app/config/config.yml**

```
sonata_admin:
  assets:
      stylesheets:
          - bundles/app/css/app.css
      javascripts:
          - bundles/app/js/app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

This assets come from configs. you can change it if this way:

**app/config/config.php**

```
sonata_admin:
  stylesheets:
    - path/in/web/directory
    - ...
  javascripts:
    - ...
    - ...
```